# confusion about solving and graphing a simple rational function

Tags: functions

given the function:

1. $\frac{x+1}{5} - 2 = -\frac{4}{x}$

I could multiply through by $5x$ yielding the quadratic with solutions $(5,4)$:

2. $x^2 - 9x + 20 = 0$

or.... I could create a common denominator of $5x$ and add fractions yielding:

$\displaystyle\frac{x(x+1)}{5x} - \frac{10x}{5x} + \frac{20}{5x}$

3. $\frac{x^2 - 9x + 20}{5x} = 0$

All three seem to have different graphs - 2 is a parabola, 3 is a hyperbola
They have different domain restrictions as well

Which is correct?  In fact, using algebra rules, I could arbitrarily divide a function by anything on both sides of the equation, changing the graph and the domain, right?  I assume that the original function (1) is what we are after but I'm confused about legitimate algebra operations changing everything.  What is the philosophy here?  Thank You!

Chris

Answer (score 0):

If $x_0$ is a solution to the equation $$f(x) = 0$$ then $x_0$ is also a solution to the equation $$f(x)g(x) = 0$$ However, the reverse is not true - if $x_0$ is a solution to $g(x) = 0$ but not to $f(x) = 0$ then it will be a solution to $f(x)g(x) = 0$. However, if there are only finitely many solutions to  $f(x)g(x) = 0$ then it is easy to check each of them individually to see whether they satisfy $f(x) = 0$ - the ones that do are all the solutions.

An important philosophical consideration here is that the equation $f(x) = 0$ and the function $f(x)$ are very different things. The former only talks about the roots of $f$ - i.e. the points where the graph crosses the x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

we have to solve
$\frac{x+1}{5}-2=\frac{-4}{x}$
and it must be $x\ne 0$ then our equation is equivalent to
$$x(x+1)-10x=-20$$
$$x^2-9x+20=0$$
the solutions are
$$\{\{x\to 4\},\{x\to 5\}\}$$